# Inject Handler into annotation controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How can I inject handler into a annotation controller(`@Controller`) without using `@Autowire`?

Comment: `@Controller` classes *are* handlers - what are you referring to?

Comment: Well I put all the business logic into 'handler' classes and inject them into controllers as needed... What's your understanding on 'handler' class? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can of course always configure autowiring in XML:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    default-autowire="byType">

    <!-- all beans here will be autowired, including those
         found by <contect:component-scan /> -->

</beans>
```

But you will probably have to supply Setter methods for the properties.

**Reference:** [Autowiring Collaborators](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire)

---

BTW, you can also use the JSR-250 `@Resource` annotation (and of course JSR-330's `@Inject`, thanks @Bozho) if you don't want to use Spring's proprietary `@Autowired` annotation.

**Reference:** [`@Resource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-resource-annotation), [`@Autowired` and `@Inject`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation)